# Сортировка списка на отсутствие null

Tags: c#

Доброй ночи. Как правильно реализовать проверку полей на null. Разбираюсь с vknet библиотекой и хочу получить список фотографии из альбома с наилучшим разрешением.
При запросе там приходит ответ с доступными размерами фото. Но у каждой фотографии свой максимальный размер.
Как правильно отсортировать входящие данные?

```
public static List<string> GetPhotoList(long ownerID, long albumID)
    {
        var photolist = new List<string>();

        var photos = vk.Photo.Get(new PhotoGetParams
        {
            OwnerId = ownerID,
            AlbumId = PhotoAlbumType.Id(albumID)
        });


        foreach (var photo in photos)
        {
          if (photo.Photo2560 != null)
                photolist.Add(photo.Photo2560.ToString());
            if (photo.Photo1280 != null)
                photolist.Add(photo.Photo1280.ToString());
        }

        return photolist;
    }
```

У меня сейчас такой вот "велосипед" но он работает не так как надо, валит в кучу повторяющиеся ссылки. Если у фотографии есть поле Photo2560 и Photo1280, то у меня в список обе ссылки вносятся. Мне хотелось бы получить отдельно фотографии в максимально доступном разрешении которое есть у конкретной фото.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понял что ToString() не возвращает нужного результата и нужно брать значения из конкретных полей. Тогда подойдет такой вариант:

```
public static List<string> GetPhotoList(long ownerID, long albumID)
{
    var photos = vk.Photo.Get(new PhotoGetParams
    {
        OwnerId = ownerID,
        AlbumId = PhotoAlbumType.Id(albumID)
    });

    var photolist = photos.Where(x => x.Photo2560 != null || x.Photo1280 != null)
                          .Select(x=> x.Photo2560?.ToString() ?? x.Photo1280.ToString())
                          .ToList();

    return photolist;
}
```

Comment: ToString, что бы из Uri в string перегнать.

Answer (score 1):

`LINQ`

```
var highPhotoSize = in photo from photos
   where photo.Photo2560 != null || photo.Photo1280 != null
   select  photo.Photo2560 != null ? photo.Photo2560.ToString() : photo.Photo1280.ToString();
```

Результатом будет `IEnumerable<string>` со всеми ссылками.